# Using another project as a library

Tags: android, github

still learning android and this is where i am stuck.
I want to use this project as a tutorial for my app
https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro
It has a wiki, and it says i need to add gradle dependency which i'm pretty sure i'll handle properly.

Whats bothering me is how do i extend that app to my class? where do i put that project/library inside my project?
Sorry if this question is newb-ish, i tried alot of things and they didn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you'd handle adding the gradle dependence I believe you are asking how to implement an Intro screen? Did you read the **How to use** part on the home page of the library?

Everything is explained there. What to extend and what each method does. For the actual creation of each fragment I will give you a hint.

After creating a new class for your Intro screen, if you don't have a specific layout for your fragment just use that part of the code:

```
 addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance(title, description, image, background_colour));
```

where the parameters are variables that you choose. For image you could use any of your images inside the drawable folder like `R.drawable.intro_ico` and for background colour - `ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.grey)`

'grey' color has to be created in your colors.xml or choose anything you like.

**EDIT:** And if you were wondering whether you should download something and where, no you are all done only by adding these lines of code to your `build.gradle`. When you add them, Android Studio asks to `Sync` the gradle file, and then it downloads the library.

For some libraries, you'd need to download a `jar` file or `git clone` from a repository and then maybe add the downloaded folder as a `Module` to your project by going *Android Studio>New>Import Module>locate the folder* . However, for that one, adding the dependency is enough as it gets downloaded after the Sync.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, i didn't know it was that easy!

Answer (score 1):

it's really very simple!
you just add these lines :

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0'
}
```

in your build.gradle file under app folder.

Comment: make this post as the answer ;)

Comment: While your answer is correct, iBobb has explained it more deeply, that's why i'm giving him the correct answer; Still, thank you for your help!